# Set a default page template to load for multi-site

Tags: multisite

I'm modifying the `install.php` (coping in from `upgrade.php`) file to load default pages that get created with a new blog is registered.

Im trying to find out how i can specify the page template that the new page will be assigned.

is there anything like `page_template =>?` Ive searched the codex but dont seem to find anything, or i have the wrong syntax idea.

current page code by default is:

```
  $first_page = sprintf( __( "This is an example page. As a new WordPress user, you should go to <a href=\"%s\">your dashboard</a> to delete this page and create new pages for your content. Have fun!" ), admin_url() );

  if ( is_multisite() )
        $first_page = get_site_option( 'first_page', $first_page );

  $first_post_guid = get_option('home') . '/?page_id=2';
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->posts, array(
                                'post_author' => $user_id,
                                'post_date' => $now,
                                'post_date_gmt' => $now_gmt,
                                'post_content' => $first_page,
                                'post_excerpt' => '',
                                'post_title' => __( 'Sample Page' ),
                                /* translators: Default page slug */
                                'post_name' => __( 'sample-page' ),
                                'post_modified' => $now,
                                'post_modified_gmt' => $now_gmt,
                                'guid' => $first_post_guid,
                                'post_type' => 'page',
                                'to_ping' => '',
                                'pinged' => '',
                                'post_content_filtered' => ''
                                ));
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->postmeta, array( 'post_id' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'default' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is anything like page_template=> but you can just specify the template like this:

```
update_post_meta($id, "_wp_page_template", "new_template.php");
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta
or using your code above:

```
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->postmeta, array( 'post_id' => 2, 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => 'new_template.php' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Probably will just use the plugin "default blog" as an overall solution but very handy code above, appreciated!